# How to get decimal point after first 2 digit?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am getting data as `123456` or `12.3456` in database using ssis i wish to transform all data in given column like `12.3456`, can anyone help here?

Comment: What is the data type of the source data?

Answer (score 1):

Add a Derived Column transformation with the following expression:

*Check if the third digit is a seperator (dot), if it is then leave the column value as it is else convert value to string and add the seperator on the third digit*

```
SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,50)[SourceColumn],3,1) == "." 
? (DT_DECIMAL,10)[SourceColumn] 
: (DT_DECIMAL,10)(LEFT((DT_WSTR,50)[SourceColumn],2) + "." + SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,50)[SourceColumn],3,LEN((DT_WSTR,50)[SourceColumn] - 2)))
```

*Note: You may remove type casting since they are added because you didn't provide anything about the column data type*

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to limit each value to only 2 decimal places use the round function as the expression within a Derived Column Transformation.

```
ROUND(((DT_NUMERIC)(SourceValue)), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
(case when value > 100 then value / 10000.0
      else value
 end)
```